# How to define a route with route params separated with a colon in Express?

Tags: javascript, express, express-router

The route I'm trying to make looks something similar to this:

```
/config/param1:param2:param3/
```

Considering `param1|2|3` are all route params the route definition should look like

```
/config/:param1::param2::param3/
```

which works good until the request is URI encoded, i.e.

```
/config/param1%3Aparam2%3Aparam3/
```

I know I could define the route twice, like

```
router.get([
    '/config/:param1::param2::param3',
    '/config/:param1%3A:param2%3A:param3'
], ...);
```

but I would really like to avoid this kind of definition. I've tried to use `encodeURIComponent`, character escaping and RegExp, but none allowed to use both ways at a time.

Is there a better way than defining the same route twice?

Comment: What does the :: represent in /config/:param1::param2::param3/ ?

Comment: @Chev a literal colon symbol followed by params `:param1` etc